# Recharts Stacked bar chart hides bar with less value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

When trying to show multiple bar charts stacked horizontally the bar with large points covers up the maximum space and the bar with less points is overlapped, How to show fix this or add minimum with to each bar as in case of value one it shows the bar clearly.

[image]

```
<ResponsiveContainer height={50} width={"100%"}>
          <BarChart
            layout="vertical"
            data={[bar]}
            margin={{left: 30, right: 50}}
            stackOffset="expand"
          >
            <XAxis hide type="number"/>
            <YAxis
              type="category"
              dataKey="name"
              fontSize="20"
              hide
            />
            <Tooltip wrapperStyle={{zIndex: 1}} cursor={{fill: 'transparent'}}/>
            {bar['Not Triggered'] && <Bar dataKey="Not Triggered" fill="#FF6D6F" stackId="a" isAnimationActive={false}>
              <LabelList
                dataKey='Not Triggered'
                position="center"
                content={renderBarCustomizedLabel}
              />
            </Bar>}
            {bar['Not Started'] && <Bar dataKey="Not Started" fill="#F9AB4B" stackId="a" isAnimationActive={false}>
              <LabelList
                dataKey="Not Started"
                position="center"
                content={renderBarCustomizedLabel}
              />
            </Bar>}
            {bar['Ongoing'] && <Bar dataKey="Ongoing" fill="#57B0E2" stackId="a" isAnimationActive={false}>
              <LabelList
                dataKey="Ongoing"
                position="center"
                content={renderBarCustomizedLabel}
              />
            </Bar>}
            {bar['completed'] && <Bar dataKey="Completed" fill="#4EA167" stackId="a" isAnimationActive={false}>
              <LabelList
                dataKey="Completed"
                position="center"
                content={renderBarCustomizedLabel}
              />
            </Bar>}
          </BarChart>
        </ResponsiveContainer>
```

Comment: Also on defining minPointSize only the last one is shown previous bar is overlapped by the next bar

Comment: I fixed it. 
first I discovered where the problem was by removing the margin completely.
then I saw that the margin was eating up space from the bar. so I think your problem is there.
try using the margin on the container div and not the barchart itself.